# Django | En local se ven las imágenes, pero en servidor no

Tags: python, django

En local se visualizan las imágenes, pero no en local. ¿Qué ocurre?

En admin del servidor ya se ve que el archivo existe:)

Servidor: Ubuntu 20.04 con Nginx.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el servidor se puede ver el archivo de la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**En servidor (no se ve la imagen):**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio en local se ve la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En local:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Settings.py:**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

Comment: Es importante que añadas mas información para poder diagnosticas el problema, por ejemplo: que usas en tu servidor, apache, nginx, el servidor de django, etc. que compartas tu settings.py que usas en local y en tu servidor.

Comment: Ya he añadido la parte setting que hace referencia a los archivos. Y esa info que pides de server. Gracias kevin.